# Is there a better way to loop through multiple decisions / assignments?

Tags: visual-workflow, bestpractice, design-patterns

Within my Visual Flow, I have a currency variable with a starting amount (Amount A).

There is a screen which asks the user to indicate (using checkboxes) if each of three additional amounts (B,C,D) should or should not be added to Amount A. The values of amounts B, C, and D are set with input fields on the same screen.

I want to check the value of each checkbox in turn, and if true, add the corresponding input amount to a sum variable.

**What is the best way to effectively "loop" through these three checkboxes / amounts?**

---

My current drafted implementation (image) uses a series of Decisions / Assignments. The Decision checks if the flag is set, and if yes, the Assignment adds the input value to my sum variable (Amount A), then moves on to the next one.

[image]

*This just doesn't seem like the most efficient way of doing this.*

Is it?  Do I accept this pattern or is there a better way?

Comment: Would it be possible to use a loop instead of if.. else  ?

Comment: That would make sense.... Can I use variable pairs - e.g. (flagB, valueB), (flagC, valueC) - in a loop?  The loop would need access to both the flag (for the check) and the value (for the assignment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite what you may think, you're doing it right.

Allow me to demonstrate a flow I wrote that would have taken me probably an hour to write in Apex Code/Visualforce.

[image: "Simple" Flow]

Loops, arrays, and the like are notoriously hard to do in Flows, and are best left done in Visualforce/Lightning.

Comment: OMG.  That's both awesome and frightening at the same time.  Thanks for the visual.  

So, to summarize: despite my developer instincts to make my little 3 item loop more efficient... The value of using the Flow makes it worthwhile to live with the quirks of writing funky if / else chains, so carry on?

Comment: @ensminger Yes, that's about the size of it. This was the minimum number of elements I could use that fulfilled the business logic. If I do find a more efficient method, I'd love to clean this up. It looks visually  cool, but this took me practically all day just to build it... *sigh*